# filtering lines from a d3.layout.tree() if they link to nodes deeper than a certain value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

With a `d3.layout.tree()` I am trying to filter a selection to contain only linking lines that link to `nodes` at a depth less than `leafDepth`

the following line is how I am trying to do that:

```
links.enter().filter(function(d){return d.target.depth < leafDepth;})....
```

without the filter the graph is drawn fine, but with the addition of the filter i get the following error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'depth' of undefined
```

You can see that I am accessing `d.target` fine in the assignment for `linkKey`. so I don't understand why `d.target` is undefined later on when i try to check `d.target.depth` which I know exists for all elements??
Am I missing something in regards to what happens when I 'pick up' the data using the identity function ?? `var link = links.selectAll("path.treeline").data( function(d){return d;} , linkKey);`

Once again this all works fine until I add the line `.filter(function(d){return d.target.depth < leafDepth;})`

Here's the main part of my graph drawing function (excluding a bunch of getter/setters that followed)

```
Tree = function () {

    var width = 1000,  //default width
        height = 1000, //default height
        left = 0,
        top = 0,
        leafDepth = 5, // depth at which leaf nodes are at
        leafClick = function (d){return console.log(d);},
        linkKey, // key function for links
        pathGenerator = d3.svg.diagonal().projection( function(d) {  
                            return [d.x, height-d.y]; }),
        childrenKey = function(d) { 
                            return (!d.values || d.values.length === 0) ? null : d.values; },
        linkKey = function(d) { return d.source.key+"_"+d.target.key; }
    ;

    function chart(selection) {
        selection.each(function (d) {

            // setup layout
            var tree = d3.layout.tree()
                .size([width,height])
                .children( function(d) {
                    return (!d.values || d.values.length === 0) ? null : d.values;
                });

            var nodeData = tree.nodes(d);
            var linkData = tree.links(nodeData);

            // 'this' is the selection
            var links = d3.select(this).selectAll("g#links")
                .data( [linkData] );

            links.enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate("+left+", "+top+")")
                .attr("id","links");

            var linkKey = function(d) { return d.source.key+"_"+d.target.key; }            
            var link = links.selectAll("path.treeline")
                .data( function(d){return d;} , linkKey);

            link.enter()
                .filter(function(d){return d.target.depth < leafDepth;}) // PROBLEM HERE !!
                .append("svg:path")
                .attr("class", "treeline")
                .attr("d", pathGenerator);

            link.transition()
                .attr("d", pathGenerator);

            link.exit()
                .remove();    

        });

        return chart;
    };

    // a bunch of getter/setters for the vars defined at top

    return chart; // this is using a version of the re-usable chart pattern by the way 
}
```

Comment: I just noticed two possibilities: 1/ filter out the nodes in nodeData before I calculate linkData. 2/ apply the filter to the identity function that is assigning the data and calculating the `join`. That said what if I wanted to colour some links differently based on depth. I would still need to be able to filter after the `join`

Answer (score 0):

moving the filter to the data assignment works, though it that means they are completely removed them from the `join`.

```
var linkLeafFilter = function(d){return d.target.depth < leafDepth;}
var link = links.selectAll("path.treeline")
                .data( function(d){return d.filter(linkLeafFilter);} , linkKey);
```